# TransactionManager is null

Tags: spring, hibernate, session, spring-mvc, transactions

i cant get `@Transactional` to work.
i have in `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<bean
    id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property
        name="sessionFactory"
        ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property
        name="dataSource"
        ref="dataSource">
    </property>
</bean>
```

the above transaction manager isn't injected anywhere.

i have in spring-servlet.xml:

```
<!-- Allows transaction to be demarcated using @Transactional within classes.-->
<tx:annotation-driven
    mode="proxy"
    proxy-target-class="true" />
```

i have a facade bean which has few DI's

```
<!-- Bean for getting a handle onto the DAO's for accessing the database. -->
<bean id="evoDaoFacade" class="com.xxx.yyy.zzz.discovery.hibernate.EvoTAMDAOFacade">
...
    <property name="topoObjectDao" ref="topoObjectDao"></property>
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
```

in my code i get the above facade into my nonspring instatiated class by :
in `spring-servlet.xml`

```
<bean
    id="ApplicationContextProvider"
    class="com.xxx.yyy.zzz.config.ApplicationContextProvider">
</bean>
```

in code:

```
EvoTAMDAOFacade evoDao = (EvoTAMDAOFacade) ApplicationContextProvider.getBean("evoDaoFacade");
```

but when i go to use the DAo accessible by facade via:

```
TopoObject topoobj = evoDao.getTopoObjectDao().findById(topoId);
```

where the findById is as follows:

```
@Transactional
public TopoObject findById( TopoObjectId id) {
        log.debug("getting TopoObject instance with id: " + id);
        try {
            TopoObject instance = (TopoObject) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                    .get("com.xxx.yyy.zzz.discovery.hibernate.TopoObject", id);
            return instance;
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("get failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }
```

i get hibernate exception saying org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here

what is wrong with my `@transactional` usage?

Comment: Probably there are issues with proxy. Try to remove `mode="proxy"` and `proxy-target-class="true"` and assign `transactionManager` explicitly. I.e. `<tx:annotation-driven transactionManager="transactionManager"/>`

Comment: no that leads to all sorts of spring exceptions proxy obv does work , although i didnt understand what it does so didnt chnage or delete it before. but now that i did i get following `nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy8] to required type [com.xxx.yyy.zzz.discovery.service.impl.Discover] for property 'dis
cover': no matching editors or conversion strategy found`

Comment: @ArunPJohny should i be using JtaTransactionManager or
<bean
 id="transactionManager"
 class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">

Comment: obv i should use HibernateTransactiionManger as i get following error if i use jts.. `Invalid property 'sessionFactory' of bean class [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager]: Bean property 'sessionFactory' is not writable or h
as an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?`